# SOLR tokenizer to store whole word as Lower case

Tags: solr

What tokenizer should I use in SOLR 4.3 to store whole word (include spaces, spl character etc) but only store as lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `KeywordTokenizerFactory` tokenizer along with the `LowerCaseFilterFactory` field descriptor.

For more details have a look [here](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Getting+Started)